# Angular6 Controlling an object in a different component

Tags: html, angular-material, angular6

I have dashboard components nested as router pages in sidenav content area. Here's the structure of the files and components.

```
app.component
   dashboard.component
      <mat-sidenav-container>
         <mat-sidenav-content>
            <router-outlet>
   cards.component
      <mat-card #Advance>
```

From the dashboard.component, I have imported cards.component…

```
import { CardsComponent } from '../cards/cards.component';
…
constructor(…, private Card: CardComponent) {}
```

Within the cards component, I have mat-cards i'd like to be able to move around based on actions in the side-nav. So their HTML has a handle, #myCard...

```
<mat-card #myCard class="myClass"></mat-card>
```

Within myClass in the .css, I have 'position: absolute;'. How can I control #myCard from a function in dashboard? For example, if I wanted to move it from a start of 20% to 40% of the area in the side-nav-content...

```
moveCard(xPos : string){
   this.Card.myCard.left = xPos;
}
```

and when I call it, something like this:

```
this.moveCard('40%');
```

Comment: document.getElementById('myCard')

Comment: A question why did you define `constructor(…, private Card: CardComponent)` you don't need an instance of `Card` and also components are not injectable

Comment: RezRahmati, I was just following intuition. It's how I have been able to access local functions in other components in the past. I was assuming I would need a local function to move the object, and then call it remotely.

Comment: Devin, I tried document.getElementById('myCard'), and it does see the object, but I don't see a .left after it. What property/attribute do I set from there to move it?